# Where do I find compassionate references to the Angel of Death

Tags: midrash, death, malach-angel, agada-stories-legends

The references that I find to the malach hamoves, Angel of Death, in our folklore and tale are largely filled with images of fear and trepidation . Where do I find stories depicting compassion?

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect such examples exist?

Comment: I doubt this qualifies as compassion but Moed Katan 28a - https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.28a.20?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en brings a case where he agreed not to take a person's life as he was logically bested by Rabbi Elazar

Comment: Is it his job to be compassionate?

Comment: I am hoping that since the maloch hamoves is in the employ of the kodesh baruch hu , the pinnacle of compassion. - that he too is compassionate as well .  I find little reference to this which is why I am asking

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

> Rabbi Levi says: Both Satan, who brought accusations against Job, and
> Peninnah, who tormented Hannah, mother of Samuel the prophet, acted
> with intent that was for the sake of Heaven. As for Satan, when he saw
> that the Holy One, Blessed be He, inclined to favor Job and praised
> him, he said: Heaven forbid that He should forget the love of Abraham.
> With regard to Peninnah, as it is written: “And her rival wife also
> provoked her sore, to make her fret” (I Samuel 1:6), i.e., Peninnah
> upset Hannah in order to motivate her to pray. Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov
> taught this in Paphunya, and Satan came and kissed his feet in
> gratitude for speaking positively about him.

Comment: Does Satan ever act compassionately ?  And which maloch is the maloch hamoves ?

Comment: @ChaninaYaacov Sorry, my answer is incomplete, the same gemara says that the Satan is the *malach ha'maves*, so if we have an example of the Satan acting with good motives then this is also a reflection on the *malach ha'maves*.